# How to run scheduled task in Spring Webflux without @Scheduled annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive

I have the following code for scheduled task that which runs after certain amount of time and condition:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void scheduleUpload() {
    Flux.interval(schedulerConfigurationProperties.getUpload().getPeriod())
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .delaySubscription(schedulerConfigurationProperties.getUpload().getInitialDelay())
            .onBackpressureBuffer(1, tick -> logger.debug("Drop tick {} in buffer", tick))
            .onBackpressureDrop(tick -> logger.debug("Drop tick {} in backpressure", tick))
            .concatMap(this::processReportUploadTick)
            .onErrorResume(this::onError)
            .subscribe();
}


public Mono<Boolean> processReportUploadTick(final Long tick) {
    return schedulerTickProcessor.processScheduledReportUploadTask(tick)
            .repeatWhen(this::hasNextUploadTask)
            .reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd)
            .doOnNext(v -> logger.debug("After processScheduledReportUploadTask tick {}", tick))
            .doFinally(s -> logger.debug("Tick finished {}", tick));
}
```

The problem is that this code runs in intervals, whereas I need it to run at specific time, for example at 10 p.m. every day. Is it possible to do with WebFlux's API, without using `org.springframework.scheduling`?

Answer (score 0):

You can delay emission of publisher, so, if your `@Scheduled` constraint is strong, I would do something like:

```java
  @Test
  public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    myTask().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(10000);
  }


  public Mono<Boolean> myTask() {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                 return LocalTime.now().getSecond() % 2 == 0;
               }).delayElement(Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(),
                                                LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.now().withNano(0).plusSeconds(1))))
               .doOnNext(t -> {
                 // Note the "previous" wording, since the computation was made during previous second.
                 System.out.println("Tick, time is: " + LocalTime.now() + ". Previous second was " + (t ? "even." : "odd."));
                 myTask().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                         .subscribe();
               });
  }
```

which outputs:

```
Tick, time is: 14:40:17.019271. Previous second was even.
Tick, time is: 14:40:18.004442. Previous second was odd.
Tick, time is: 14:40:19.005974. Previous second was even.
Tick, time is: 14:40:20.005954. Previous second was odd.
Tick, time is: 14:40:21.004746. Previous second was even.
Tick, time is: 14:40:22.001688. Previous second was odd.
Tick, time is: 14:40:23.004613. Previous second was even.
Tick, time is: 14:40:24.002388. Previous second was odd.
Tick, time is: 14:40:25.002254. Previous second was even.
Tick, time is: 14:40:26.006743. Previous second was odd.
```

You can apply this to your code (I did not copy it for I lack multiple variables).

> Note: I am not an expert using Reactor and that might violate some best practices.

> Note 2: My schedule works at the second level, you can of course do the same interval computation with hours, days,...